# how to combine like and between in sql?

Tags: sql

`select Salary from employees where salary between like '3%' and like '4%';`

I have tried the above statement but I am getting an error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, etc.)?  We would most likely need to know this to help you.  Also, can you add sample input data, along with the expected output?

Comment: Also please show us a few records of sample data to clarify your intent. As it is, it is hard to make sense of your query.

Comment: Is `salary` a varchar/char column ?

Comment: Why you match salary with `like` operator ? generally  it's used to match char/varchar type.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do, what result you want to get? The mix of a probably numeric "salary" and a varchar-specific "like" operator is confusing

Answer (score 1):

if you know the length of the salary, for example, if it is 4 digits. you can use this

```
select Salary from employees where salary between 3000 and 4999;
```

otherwise,

```
select Salary from employees where LEFT(CAST(salary AS varchar(50)),1)  between '3' and '4';
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the correct way to do your task.

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employees WHERE Salary LIKE '3%' OR '4%'
```

Comment: a) I don't think `LIKE '3%' OR '4%'` is a correct syntax; b) filtering a column named *salary* (which is probably numeric) with  a "like" operator is strange

Comment: I have tried in my database on integer data type and it worked. Please try it once so, I can confirm

Comment: Invalid query. `'4%'` is a boolean expression and should have a boolean data type.

Comment: What datatype your salary column have?